# Ember.Application.create Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember v1.9+ you get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 2.0. 
Please see more details at http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your version of handlebars as is stated in the Error.  You can find version 2.0 here: http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v2.0.0.js

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 1.9.0 (which will be released to beta on October 24th and stable on December 5th) support for Handlebars 1.x will be removed, and support for Handlebars 2.0 introduced.

Have a look at it

http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html